# Avoid asp.net application run in particular browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a scenario I need to avoid my ASP.Net web application should not run in Firefox. If any one tries to open my application it will redirect to Chrome or Internet Explorer. I don't know how achieve this
situation.

Is it possible to handle this using JQuery or JavaScript ?

Comment: Your question is fundamentally flawed... you cannot make a browser on a clients computer make a DIFFERENT browser open

Comment: The best you could do is display something different if the "wrong" browser was used. But why would you want to restrict your users like this? It would almost certainly make me never want to visit your site again.

Comment: yes absolutely right but is it possible to handle this in c# code behind.

Comment: I'm curious to know more about this 'scenario' :) Maybe you should rethink your requirements.

Comment: Some controls and my application UI is not supported in particular browser. It will fully supported in IE @David

Comment: @dinesh.k Then perhaps you should change the controls you are using?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the presumption is flawed.

Comment: I don't understand why all the downvotes. It's a legitimate question, and this topic is useful Q&A reference material. Just because the answer may seem self-evident to some of us, that doesn't mean it's not something that's reasonable to ask and needs to be explained.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple answer**: No

**Longer answer...**

Your question is fundamentally flawed - you simply cannot make a browser on a computer open a *different* browser on the same computer.

If you *could* to that, it would be a massive security flaw... and that is why you can't.

---

Although I don't like saying it - you *could* write an OCX (active X control) that would probably allow you to do it... but that would only work in Internet Explorer - and would require the user to install it.

But as you want to move *from* FireFox, this obviously doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. You can't force a browser to open another application on the client machine (beside some browser plugins, like Adobe PDF).

Think what would happen if I could open your bank's application though javascript.

Comment: I'm utterly intrigued... please, downvoter, explain why this deserves a -1??

Comment: You're welcome - just simply don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible in technical sense. But if you try to do this way you may invite unnecessary issues from other browsers and loose focus on main objective.